# vb.net erros when trying to access com port with baud rate of 921600

Tags: serial-port, baud-rate

I am trying to access a com port using USB to UART for a throughput test on a device and a requirement of this is a Baud rate of 921600. I am using vb.net and a Baud rate of 460800 works just fine.

The connection works just fine on TeraTerm at a Baud rate 921600. When I try a loopback test at 921600 Baud, I get the following

> the output  is expecting f in ASCII (01100110 in binary) to ÷ in ASCII
>   (11110110 in binary).

my best guess is that the program isn't able to read information fast enough. Since TeraTerm works, I am assuming that it isn't my hardware, it probably is vb.net. Is there a easy fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer to the problem, for some reason when compiled as an x86 processor, it does not work. I switched it to x64 under

> project -> properties -> compiler

and it works.

EDIT:
Using com ports above 9 breaks everything as well, use a com port 9 or below.